# How do I validate my input field to request some text to be entered?

Tags: javascript, reverse, palindrome

I am just doing a reverse a word challenge. I have the code and all works fine I just need to create a validation that requires the user to input some type of text. At the moment if you click submit without any text in the field it still returns that it is a palindrome. Not sure what to add in there to request some text or tell the user that they need to type text.

```js
document.getElementById("flipBtn").addEventListener("click", function () {

    //Here is what happens when the button is clicked.

    // Step 1 - Get the Data
    let inputWord = document.getElementById("reverseString").value;

    // Step 2 - Work with the Data
    let lowerInput = inputWord.toLowerCase();
    lowerInput = lowerInput.replace(" ", "");
    let reverseWord = ""

    //First is the Loop Variable followed by a ;.
    //Second part is how many times we are looping. Until the second part is false.
    //Third is what happens after each loop. ++ means add 1, -- = subtract 1.
    //[] indicates array position.
    //A string is an array of characters.
    //string word = [w][o][r][d]
    //               0  1  2  3
    //Without the - 1 you get index out of range exception.
    //Maybe there is a JavaScript method to make all the letters LowerCase.
    //Maybe you want to store four variables, the original input, that reversed, and the lowercase version of each for comparison.
    for (let loop = inputWord.length - 1; loop >= 0; loop--) {
        reverseWord += lowerInput.charAt(loop);

    };
    let otherReverse = lowerInput.split("").reverse().join("");


    // Step 3 - Output the result
    if (lowerInput == reverseWord) {
        document.getElementById("reverseOutput").innerHTML = `The word that you entered: ${reverseWord} was changed to: ${otherReverse} is a Palindrome`;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("reverseOutput").innerHTML = `The word that you entered: ${reverseWord} was changed to: ${otherReverse} is not a Palindrome`;
    }

    document.getElementById("reverseString").addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {

        var character = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;

        if (character >= 97 && character <= 122 ||
            character >= 65 && character <= 90 || character == 8 || character == 9 || character == 32) {
            return true;
        }
        else {

            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }

    });
})
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row card"><span class="custfont">Reverse A String</span>
                <br />
                <div class="col"><input class="input" type="text" id="reverseString" placeholder="Enter your text..." /></div>
                <br />
                <div class="col"><button class="btn custbtn btn-dark button" id="flipBtn">Flip the String</button></div>
                <br />
                <div class="col"><span id="reverseOutput"></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get what exactly you want, it's may help you:

Just added

```
if (inputWord.trim().length === 0) {
    return false;
}
```

To check the input length.

```js
document.getElementById("flipBtn").addEventListener("click", function () {

    //Here is what happens when the button is clicked.

    // Step 1 - Get the Data
    let inputWord = document.getElementById("reverseString").value;

    // Step 2 - Work with the Data
    let lowerInput = inputWord.toLowerCase();
    lowerInput = lowerInput.replace(" ", "");
    let reverseWord = ""

    //First is the Loop Variable followed by a ;.
    //Second part is how many times we are looping. Until the second part is false.
    //Third is what happens after each loop. ++ means add 1, -- = subtract 1.
    //[] indicates array position.
    //A string is an array of characters.
    //string word = [w][o][r][d]
    //               0  1  2  3
    //Without the - 1 you get index out of range exception.
    //Maybe there is a JavaScript method to make all the letters LowerCase.
    //Maybe you want to store four variables, the original input, that reversed, and the lowercase version of each for comparison.
    for (let loop = inputWord.length - 1; loop >= 0; loop--) {
        reverseWord += lowerInput.charAt(loop);

    };
    let otherReverse = lowerInput.split("").reverse().join("");


    // Step 3 - Output the result
    if (lowerInput == reverseWord) {
        document.getElementById("reverseOutput").innerHTML = `The word that you entered: ${reverseWord} was changed to: ${otherReverse} is a Palindrome`;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("reverseOutput").innerHTML = `The word that you entered: ${reverseWord} was changed to: ${otherReverse} is not a Palindrome`;
    }

})

document.getElementById("reverseString").addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
  if ( document.getElementById("reverseString").value.length > 0 ) {
    document.getElementById("flipBtn").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("flipBtn").disabled = true;
  }
}); 

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row card"><span class="custfont">Reverse A String</span>
            <br />
            <div class="col"><input required class="input" type="text" id="reverseString" placeholder="Enter your text..." /></div>
            <br />
            <div class="col"><button class="btn custbtn btn-dark button" disabled id="flipBtn">Flip the String</button></div>
            <br />
            <div class="col"><span id="reverseOutput"></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that and it does not work. I am just trying to make my input field require some text be entered for the program to run. Currently it doesn't require any text in the input field. You can still click Flip the String and it will tell you that the empty field is a palindrome. I don't want the program to run unless there is text in the input field.

Comment: Could you check it again please?

Comment: It is not giving me an error Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null on main.js: line 14

Comment: You did change the HTML too? I added a new <span> item in your HTML code

Comment: Please check it again, I totally changed it and validate the input and if the input is empty, the button will be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to go about this.

You could disable the button to prevent the user from submitting the button. The input tag has a `disabled` attribute that can be set to prevent users from submiting a form. You can have a function that runs on every `keyUp` to check the input's length and if empty, set the submit button to disabled.

```html
<div class="col"><input class="input" onkeyup="validate()" type="text" id="reverseString" placeholder="Enter your text..." /></div>
```

```js
function validate() {
const input = document.getElementById("reverseString").value;

     if(input.trim() === "") { 
            document.getElementById('flipBtn').disabled = true; 
        } else { 
            document.getElementById('flipBtn').disabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a user friendly solution since it implies that the input is required and prevents users from submitting an empty or whitespace input.

You can also include a checker in the main submit function that can prevent the rest of the function to run if the input is empty.

```js
document.getElementById("flipBtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
    let inputWord = document.getElementById("reverseString").value;
    if(!inputWord.trim()){
      return;
    }
    //...rest of logic
})
```

This is also a valid solution and is recommended to have both.